# Why is the minimum value always zero in this program?

Tags: java

I keep getting zero as minimum value. I know it has something to do with the minimum value initialized to zero but I can't wrap my head around it and change to properly.

**My code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;  

public class InputPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float average;
        int NumberofIntegers = 0;
        double total = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of Integers: ");

        NumberofIntegers = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= NumberofIntegers; i++) {
            System.out.print("Entered Value " + i + " :  ");
            total += input.nextDouble();
        }

        int minValue = 0;
        int maxValue = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= NumberofIntegers; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter value number " + i + " again: ");
            int inputNumbers = input.nextInt();

            if (inputNumbers > maxValue) {
                maxValue = inputNumbers;
            } else if (inputNumbers < minValue){
                minValue = inputNumbers;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum Value: " + maxValue);
        System.out.println("Minimum Value: " + minValue);
        System.out.println("Average : " + (total / NumberofIntegers));
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you initialize minValue to 0. Initialize it to Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Comment: You should itinialize `minValue` to the maximum possible: `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Ask yourself how you expect it to become anything *other* than 0. Hint: if you give it negative numbers, it will go less than 0. If you *only* give negative numbers, your maximum will (incorrectly) be 0. Oh, and consider whether you really want that `else`. If you have just a single number, the min and max should be the same, right?

Comment: to add on the previous commands, for the same reson initialize the max value `Integer.MIN_VALUE` aswell. Additionally the repeated input of the values looks weird, you could handle everything in a single loop if you´d be using a proper array.

Comment: If you start with 0, you need a number less than that to change it. Stepping through your code in your debugger should make this clearer.

Comment: Also, follow name conventions: NumberofIntegers  -> numberOfIntegers

Answer (score 2):

Wrong initialization.Simply said - 0 is always less than any of your numbers.

MIN must be MAX_VALUE, while MAX must be MIN_VALUE ( or 0 for positive numbers )

OR

you can use the first number of input as both starting MIN and MAX.